# Is a game's world-wide visibility in app stores affected by the publisher's country of residence?

Tags: marketing, sales

I've noticed on Apple Store (and I assume on Google Playstore too) I find different games and apps in France than in the US. Does this mean if my company resides in a small country and I register my game in this country, it'll only be shown to users of my country? Or is it just a matter of some settings and I can decide to be shown all around the world, for instance for American users (which is a larger market than my country), same as game producers living there?

Does a game developer's country of residence influence how many downloads world-wide he can reach at all?

My question is about Apple Store and Google Playstore, but answers for other platforms are welcome too.

Comment: I would assume it's rather based on regional popularity of the app, but the ranking algorithms of app stores are mysterious.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can just set in the PlayStore and Apple Store settings in which countries you want it to be available so it doesn't matter where your company is registered, it'll potentially reach the same audience if you set world-wide visibility. Or that's how I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Brand value is local. In most places, when people hear "Ghirardelli" they think nothing of it, or they guess it's a pizza place, yet in very few places of the world people will think of chocolate.

App stores rank popular apps highly, and popularity is local. A French developer can indeed launch a game that becomes a huge hit in the US, and has no success in France.

You can also compare it to music, which shows us a peculiarity: Some countries are better than average at exporting their brands to other countries, due to language, the way media works, etc. So if you launch from such a country you have better chances to become popular worldwide.